# Is there a function to filter rows that contains a string, but on chosen columns names that contains a given string in R?

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

i will try to be as specific as possible.
I get chunks of datasets from web application. Number of columns may vary for each dataset i download. I want to filter my data for outliers. So i prepared a list:

```
outl <- c("God","Devil","Priest")
```

Now lets assume this is my df:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4)
Actor1<- c("Driver","","","")
Actor2<- c("President","Zombie","","")
Actor3<- c("CEO","Devil","","")
Actor4<-c("Priest","","Killer","Mayor")
Leng<- c(12,42,42,22)
Genre<-c("horror","criminal","drama","comedy")
df_ex <-data.frame(ID, Actor1, Actor2, Actor3, Actor4, Leng, Genre)
```

i would like to filter for the rows ids that contains names from outlier in ANY column that has "Actor" in name (there could be 100 of them thats why i cant do it with OR operator), so something like:

```
df_ex %>%
  filter(*anycolumn that contains string "Actor"* %in% outl)
```

and i would expect to get rows with ids 1 & 2

hope thats clear enough,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter_at` to specifically filter based on specific selected variables (in this case, those starting with "Actor").

```
library(tidyverse)

df_ex %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Actor")), any_vars(. %in% outl))
```

**Output**

```
  ID Actor1    Actor2 Actor3 Actor4 Leng    Genre
1  1 Driver President    CEO Priest   12   horror
2  2           Zombie  Devil          42 criminal
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
df_ex[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df_ex[startsWith(names(df_ex), "Actor")], `%in%`, outl)), ]
#   ID Actor1    Actor2 Actor3 Actor4 Leng    Genre
#1  1 Driver President    CEO Priest   12   horror
#2  2           Zombie  Devil          42 criminal
```